# Query data with Firebase with OrderByChild

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have the following data structure

```
{
  "advisors" : {
    "0ea9bab6-415e-4900-8698-ac03a1ef4518" : {
      "description" : "",
      "price" : 0,
      "title" : ""
    },
    "cc31c353-ca6a-440d-b188-af2016f72aef" : {
      "description" : "",
      "price" : 0,
      "title" : ""
    },
    "d8403e9b-fb74-4425-874f-2d125cd07a68" : {
      "description" : "I know every corner in the arab countries.",
      "price" : "50",
      "title" : "Best guide in the middle east"
    }
  },
  "advisors-countries" : {
    "0ea9bab6-415e-4900-8698-ac03a1ef4518" : {
      "Angola" : "true"
    },
    "cc31c353-ca6a-440d-b188-af2016f72aef" : {
      "Angola" : "true"
    }
  },
```

I want to make the following query: Give me all the prices of the advisors which have Angola in their list.

I tried the next code for retrieve only the child of Advisor-countries where Angola=true.

```
var advisors = (ref.orderByChild("Angole").equalTo(true));
$scope.users = $firebaseArray(advisors);
console.log("sync ", $scope.users);
```

But I'm keep getting null object in the advisors object.

Comment: What is your ref exactly?

Comment: There is a typo on your first code line `var advisors = (ref.orderByChild("Angola").equalTo(true));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do your query easily with AngularFire you'll need to rework your data structure.

```
"advisors-countries" : {
    "0ea9bab6-415e-4900-8698-ac03a1ef4518" : {
      "Angola" : "true",
      "price": 0
    },
    "cc31c353-ca6a-440d-b188-af2016f72aef" : {
      "Angola" : "true",
      "price": 0
    }
}
```

You should include the price in and any other relevant data in the `advisors-countries` location. If you're worried about duplicating data, that's okay. [You can use multi-path updates to keep your data consistent](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html).

Then your query would work:

```
var query = ref.orderByChild("Angola").equalTo(true);
```

**Now, why you're seeing null for `$scope.users`.**

When you log `$scope.users` to the console, it's going to be `null` because there's no data at first. Downloading the data is an asynchronous action, so it won't be available at first.

To debug this action, use `$loaded()`.

```
$scope.users = $firebaseArray(advisors);
$scope.users.$loaded().then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data === $scope.users);
});
```

In the first log, you'll get whatever data exists. In the second log, you'll see that the `data` param is the same as the `$scope.users` object. What this means is that you don't have use `$loaded()`, because when the becomes available it will be used in your template.